# Do Spring security support Windows Active directory

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-kerberos, ntlm-authentication

My application is based upon NTLM authentication which 
uses Windows Active Directory authentication. We are moving to Windows 10 and have to move on to some better authentication based on name + domain name. Can I go ahead with Spring security? Or does someone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Did you try a web search for e.g. [`spring security windows single sign on`](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+security+windows+single+sign+on)? Did you look at the articles found, e.g. [Introduction to SPNEGO/Kerberos Authentication in Spring | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-kerberos)?

Comment: Thanks a ton . I have done a searches but was not getting sure if spring security have any windows active directory Authentication . Thanks a lot :)